# nested 'while' loop not looping back to outer 'for' loop after finishing (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I'm needing to find how much tax $ any given number of taxpayers have to pay over any number of years. At the beginning of the program, # of taxpayers is entered, and # of years is entered. The while loop executes fine, and does what it's supposed to do the first time; however, it never loops back to the 'for' loop & asks for the next taxpayer's income. (I will note I have to do it this way as it's for a class)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= taxpayers; i++)
{
  while (year <= years)
    {      
     cout << "\n\nPlease enter payer " << i << "'s income for year " << year << ": $";
        cin >> income;
        
         if (income >= 0)
         {
           .......
                         
          year++;
         }
         
         else
         {
         cout << "\n    *Error*"
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
         continue;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cout << "\n    *Error*" cin.clear();` isn't valid C++ code. Please [update your quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71699793/edit) and post *real* code as a proper [mcve] that reproduces your problem. For the shown code, that would include the `#include` stack, a `main`, and a primer that sets up `taxpayers`, `years`, `year`, and `income` (static hard-values  is fine).

Comment: The example is incomplete. Provide a [mre]. Also, have you stepped this through a debugger? If not, that's your first step.

Comment: Look out for accidentally changing `i` in the `...` part of your while loop. But as the others have said, there's no way we can answer this definitively if you don't give us all of the relevant code. Also consider: What do you do if someone types something that's not a number when you try to read the income from cin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it never loops back to the 'for' loop & asks for the next taxpayer's income

That is because after the `while` loop is finished the 1st time through, `year` has caught up to `years`, and so on subsequent iterations of the `for` loop, `year <= years` is always false.

You need to reset `year` back to its starting value on each iteration of the `for` loop, before entering the `while` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= taxpayers; i++)
{
    year = <your 1st year>; // <-- HERE
    while (year <= years)
    {      
        ...
    }
}
```